# Atom is running slow when edit a file which is over 500 lines

Tags: editor, atom-editor

when I use Atom to edit javascript files there has some performance issues, if the js script lines is over a number of amount, e.g, 500, to scroll the file or move cursor will be stuck. It should not because hardware problems and 500 lines is also not a big amount. Is there something I can do to make Atom to run smoothly when I edit a big size file? Thanks,

Comment: please go to *SuperUser*. This is a programming forum, not *how to use a computer?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem occurs is because a plugin -- linter-jscs, 500 lines is not big amount, after disable this plugin, editing is on right way.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in [this article](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/12049), this is an ongoing issue with Atom and is currently being dealt with by the team. I don't believe it has anything to do with computer performance.

I currently run an i7 machine and, when opening large (typically minified) files, the editor will run extremely slow and, in some instances, crash completely.

Hopefully we can see a resolution soon.

Comment: Atom is awesome, hopefully we can see a resolution soon

Comment: Completely agree

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the possibility that your machine may just be slow?

I understand this doesn't directly address your question, but if you're not bound to Atom you could experiment with other text editors. I personally recommend Visual Studio Code. Have a look:

https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Comment: My MacBook run most applications smoothly. I also use NetBeans, the performance is good. Anyway, thanks your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Although you've posted a solution, it may be worth considering using a package such as [Timecop](https://atom.io/packages/timecop), which displays information about where time is spent while Atom loads. You can also check similar information in the `Settings > Packages` view, which will list how much time each installed package will add to the startup time (see the [Flight Manual section on packages](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/atom-packages/)).